# Making the image go full screen in slideshow application in winforms

Tags: c#, image, winforms, fullscreen

I have an winforms application for slideshow of images.im using a list for storing the list of image paths,picture box to display image and on click of [slideshow] button..the slideshow happens...everything is working fine but i have one problem with full screen of image... on click of slideshow,image should open in full screen same like windows image viewer. please help me,keep in mind,only image should go full screen.not the full form.

i got below code in almost all the sites but Windowstate shows an error.

```
            targetForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            targetForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            targetForm.TopMost = true;
            targetForm.Bounds = Screen.GetBounds(targetForm);
```

please help me out.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use different layouts for windowed and full screen mode.

When you switch to full screen you can:

- programatically change `PictureBox` to fill the form with `pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill`
- open another form (in full screen) that contains only the `PictureBox` that fills the form

Note:
First method won't work as expected if you have other controls with Dock set to something else  than `DockStyle.None`