# how to display the image as fullscreen mode using c#.net in winforms

Tags: c#

I am designing a login page in Win forms after click login the screen gets full screen mode but the background image gets half of the screen not shown as full screen. I need the background image also shown in full screen mode.

What I have tried:

```
FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Picturebox dock property to fill..

Comment: Try this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793179/making-the-image-go-full-screen-in-slideshow-application-in-winforms

Comment: Not Working....

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the SizeMode of pictureBox control

```
    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

you can use form background image without using pictureBox control

```
  this.BackgroundImage = Resources.bg_image ;
  this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap myPicture = new Bitmap("a.png");
        pictureBox1.Image = myPicture;
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }
```

More information can be found in [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode?view=net-5.0#:~:text=Using%20the%20StretchImage%20value%20causes,to%20always%20fit%20the%20image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode?view=net-5.0#:%7E:text=Using%20the%20StretchImage%20value%20causes,to%20always%20fit%20the%20image).